# IE doesn't open href HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer, href

I have the following `href` that I needed to look like a button

```
<td><a href="/link.jsp" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" value="Log in"></input></a></td>
```

The problem is that `IE11` does not open the link at all. It does not react to it. All of the other browsers do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should get rid of the input type submit (it's meant to submit a form). Wrap your anchor around a button image.  See example below:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">
<img  src="http://imageurl" />
</a>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the regular `html` look of the button where the `img src` is?

Comment: sure.  just use a tool like visio to create a button.  it pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot put an `input` inside an `a`.

Write real HTML and you won't have this problem. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

If you want a link: Use a link.

If you want to submit a form: Use a submit button.

If you don't like the way an element looks by default: Use CSS.